# Question regarding cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $\bigl\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\bigr\}$ is a subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, where $\Bbb R$ is the set of real numbers.
>
> Is the given set also the cartesian product of two subsets of $\Bbb R$?

Does

$$X=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid 1>x>-1\}\\Y=\left\{y\in\Bbb R\mid\left((\forall x\in X)\left[-\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]\right)\right\}$$

define infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ for given $x$, such that $y$ suffices the condition in $Y$?

Also, could there be two other sets (except of just, in this case, replacing "$x$" with "$y$", "$y$" with "$x$", "$X$" with "$Y$" and "$Y$" with "$X$"), whose cartesian product yields the given subset?

Comment: Very Clever. Copied the images. How much time you put in doing it?

Comment: @MonK I can't find those images on other sites by using google search-by-image. And they probably won't be taken from math.stackexchange since they're not rendered in LaTeX. So I'm not certain that they've been copy-pasted.

Comment: No, I think you also din't get it. He has an image on his system. He took snip images out of it, put it over here in places in bits and pieces :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more we know about your efforts and thinking, the easier it will be for us to help you (and the more likely it will be that people will *want* to help you).

Comment: Why do you think I copied them? I used Word, Snapping Tool (in windows 7) and microsoft Paint to save the pics. Anyhow, this problem is given in the first set of exercises about cartesian products, so really I've no experience about it, Cameron Buie.

Comment: "A function f from X to Y is a subset of the Cartesian product X × Y subject to the following condition: every element of X is the first component of one and only one ordered pair in the subset.[4] In other words, for every x in X there is exactly one element y such that the ordered pair (x, y) is contained in the subset defining the function f." (from wikipedia page "Function (mathematics)") - how then could you have functions, like y=sqrt(1-x^2), if none of them (X, Y) is to be defined in terms of the other? That is, what do you mean by "simple pair"?

Answer (score 4):

If you define $Y$ that way, then $Y=\{0\}$. That's because when $y\neq 0$, with $-1<y<1$, then for $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$, $x\in X$ it is obviously not true that $-\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\sqrt{1-x^2}$. So $y\notin Y$.

If $U=X\times Y$ then if $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1)\in U$ then $(x_2,y_2)\in U$. When $X,Y\subseteq \mathbb R$, this can be read as:

> If three corners of an "axis-aligned" rectangle are in $U$, then the fourth corner is, too.

Now, $U=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$ is a unit disk. Can you think of an axis-aligned rectangle with three points inside $U$ but the fourth outside?

Comment: @availanche Nope, there is such a rectangle. Try again.

Comment: Such a rectangle does not exist, because the fourth vertex shares coordinates of the already existing 3 vertices, which are, at any order, define a point that is not outside the unit disk. I wanted to form ordered pairs, where, if the first coordinate is x, the second coordinate is limited by -sqrt(1-x^2) and sqrt(1-x^2). Does the cartesian product of two closed intervals always geometrically correspond to a rectangle?

Comment: Sorry, you are still wrong. Draw a circle. Can you create a rectangle with three points inside the circle and the fourth outside?

Comment: Well, yes, I succeeded in finding infinitely many such surprising rectangles, in regard to the unit circle: take the points (0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -0.7), (g, -0.5) and (g, -0.7), where -(sqrt (51))/10>g>-(sqrt(3))/2...Oh I see, in regards to "If three corners of an "axis-aligned" rectangle are in U, then the fourth corner is, too." theorem, it means that a circle cannot be the result of any cartesian product, hence disks cannot be so as well.

Comment: You can just use $(0,0)$, $(x,0)$, $(0,y)$ and $(x,y)$ with $x,y\in(-1,1)$ and $x^2+y^2>1$....

Comment: It is clear that if I do it, I could take any real numbers x,y, where 1>|x|>1/sqrt(2) and 1>|y|>1/(sqrt2), where 1/sqrt(2) is 0.707, to the precision of 3 digits after the decimal point (i.e., for example, take any values of x,y less than 1 and greater than 0.71 in absolute value).

Comment: Yes, but you really only need one such rectangle to show that $U$ is not $X\times Y$ for any sets $X,Y$.

Answer (score 0):

The given set is not cartesian product of two subsets X,Y of the reals;

Supoosing X,Y are subsets of the reals whose Cartesian product is the unit disk (excluding the unit circle), it also means that their cartesian product corresponds to an axis-aligned rectangle.

In this case, the following theorem holds: "If three corners of an "axis-aligned" rectangle are in U, then the fourth corner is, too" (worded by Thomas Andrews), where U=XxY.

But, in case of circle with radius r, one may choose 3 points, each of which is a subset of the cartesian product of X and Y: (0,0), (x,0), (0,y) and (x,y), where x,y belong to the opened interval (-1,1), and x^2+y^2>r^2 (specifically, it would mean that at least one of |x|, |y|, must be greater than r/sqrt(2), otherwise their sum cannot be greater than r^2).

Therefore, we deduce that the given disk (x^2+y^2<1) cannot be the cartesian product of two subsets of R.

Comment: It would be better and clear if you have used images in your answer too :)

Comment: Here is some relevant demonstration from desmos (finding such configuration for the unit circle itself: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yglrzwlmkt